# Finding reasonable change of variables?

Tags: integration

Let $R \subseteq R^{2}$  be the ﬁrst quadrant region bounded by the curves 
$x^2 + y^2 =4, x^2 + y^2 =9, x^2 −y^2 =1$ and $x^2 − y^2 =4$. 
Use an appropriate change of variables to evaluate.

$$\iint   (xy) \, dA
$$

So i tried letting 
$u= x^2 +y^2$ and $v=x^2 - y^2$  (also tried numerous other without succeeding)

so i get 
$$
\int_{1}^{4} \int_{4}^{9}  \sqrt{\frac{u+v}{2} }  \sqrt{\frac{v-u}{2} } \, du dv
$$

which is a bit of a mess and not what i'd like to even try in an exam. This surely isn't the easiest change of variable?   anybody have any suggestions?
$\LaTeX Rookie$

Comment: Did you check $u=x^2$ and $v=y^2$?

Comment: What do you need to evaluate

Comment: @teddybear ahh... well I thought about it and I just pushed it aside, ahah silly me, i'll try it now thanks

Comment: @teddybear Actually in my moment of madness using latex for the first time I left out a bit of the question. not that it makes much difference. and it turns out that I did try your suggestion but i dont know how to do it. Ive been at it for ages

Comment: I am assuming you don't have to find the limits which I think is the real intuition behind the question if you make that substitution area would be $\int\int dudv$ as u and v are all linear in the equation so now substituting back them gives $\int\int 4xydudv $ as it asks for first quadrant divide it by 4.

Comment: @teddybear I'm pretty sure you do have to find limits, because there was another question like this that we did and it worked out nicely.  It's just to try find an easier region to integrate because as it is in x and y we cant integrate it in one single iterated integral because of how its described, we'd have to break it up.